# Sample grouped rows from a data frame/tibble in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I have a following data set

```
df = data.frame("Country" = rep(sample(c("USA", "Germany", "Japan", "Slovakia", "Togo")),2))
df$Value = sample(c(1:1000), 10)
```

Now I want to randomly sample from that df, lets say, 3 countries. Which means I want to have all 6 rows pertaining to 3 countries. So every time I decide to sample from a variable country, I always get all (here two) rows that pertain to that country.

How could I do it, the following code doesnt work all the time, returning sometimes 2 countries only

```
df %>% filter(Country %in% sample(Country, 3))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap with `unique` to remove the duplicates from 'Country' and use that in the `sample` to make sure that there would be always 3 `sample` 'Country'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(Country %in% sample(unique(Country), 3))
```